# Querying only 400 characters from the database won't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have this line of code:

```
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, LEFT(body, 400), category FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=posts.category_id ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

The `LEFT(body,400)` won't query 400 characters only, it will query all but the last word. 
This is the code I use to echo the query (its in a while loop w/ db)

```
<p><?php
     $body_sub = substr($body, 0). "...<a href='post.php?id=$post_id'> Continue Reading →</a>";
    echo nl2br($body_sub);
?></p>
```

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL) is your friend.

Comment: Be extremely careful to use placeholders for any and all user data. `$start` and `$per_page` should not be interpolated in your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column `body` does not technically exist after you use it in a function. You need to alias the column:

```
... LEFT(body, 400) AS body
```

Then call `body`.

I would also recommend using backticks around system terms such as columns:

```
SELECT `post_id`, 
       `title`, 
       LEFT(`body`, 400) AS `body`, 
       `category`
FROM   `posts`
       INNER JOIN `categories` 
               ON `categories`.`category_id` = `posts`.`category_id` 
ORDER  BY `post_id` DESC 
LIMIT  $start, $per_page
```